# Embedding google drive folder using embeddedfolderview does not seem to work anymore

Tags: directory, google-drive-api, embed

Apparently the google drive *embeddedfolderview* function is not being rendered anymore.

For ex. this folder is public, you can access it even in incognito mode: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0B_0Ab9ZYwkZzNFbzNWbWtLSkU?resourcekey=0-G7RnuTSb1qRJ55nGXkSofw&usp=sharing yet, you can't open it embedded in a page, try opening the iframe src: https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=0B0B_0Ab9ZYwkZzNFbzNWbWtLSkU#grid

If you are logged in into google you'll be prompted with a typical google request access message, if you are not logged in you'll be asked to login into google and then be prompted with a typical google request access message.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? I assume this has something to do with recent google update on some google drive functionality, and hope someone has looked for a workaround on this.

Comment: a better way to embed google drive in a website would be : https://medium.com/@thesumitsingh/how-to-embed-google-drive-folder-files-with-1-line-of-code-e445af55d8fd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... and now I found the real fix:
iframe src: https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=0B0B_0Ab9ZYwkZzNFbzNWbWtLSkU&resourcekey=0-G7RnuTSb1qRJ55nGXkSofw#grid

Comment: Yes, i confirm, adding the resourcekey variable makes embedding work again. Great! Big thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Best workaround I have found so far:
<object data="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=0B0B_0Ab9ZYwkZzNFbzNWbWtLSkU#grid" width="600" height="400" > Use
<a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0B_0Ab9ZYwkZzNFbzNWbWtLSkU?resourcekey=0-G7RnuTSb1qRJ55nGXkSofw&usp=sharing">this link</a> to see directory contents </object>"

The advantage of the Object tag is that you can give an alternative if the URL  not render. In the coding example above I've used your URLs.
Assuming the directory is public, the folder view it will appear for anybody who is signed in to Google. Otherwise, they will see the alternative link

Comment: Also thanks for letting me know that I'm not the only one with this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I didn't have a resourcekey for the folder being shared. The following worked for me:

`https://drive.google.com/u/0/embeddedfolderview?id=[FOLDERID]&pli=1#list`

The `/u/0/` part seems to be important. Removing it would ask for a login, unless (oddly) you are in incognito mode, when it works just fine.